# Kohana error sending email trying to avoid spam filters

Tags: php, email, kohana, spam-prevention

Our website is built in PHP, using Kohana framework.

We had a spam issue sending emails with Kohana, so we are trying to edit our code with spam prevention.

The issue we have right now is a Kohana error that reads:

```
Exception
system/vendor/swift/Swift.php [345]:
The sender parameter must either be a valid string email address or an instance of Swift_Address.
```

This was our old code:

```
/*
 * E-mail sender
 */
$swift = email::connect();
$email_message = new View('email/email_template');
$subject = "This is our subject";
$from = "subdomain@domain.org";
```

And this is the new code we want to implement:

```
/*
 * E-mail sender
 */
$swift = email::connect();
$email_message = new View('email/email_template');
$subject = "This is our subject";
/*$from = "subdomain@domain.org";*/

//Avoiding SPAM filters
$header = "";
$from = $header;
$header .= "Reply-To: ". $user->firstname . " " . $user->lastname ." <". $user->email .">\r\n"; 
$header .= "Return-Path: ". $user->firstname . " " . $user->lastname ." <". $user->firstname . "@realFromAccordingToGoogle.org>\r\n"; 
$header .= "From: ". $user->firstname . " " . $user->name ." <subdomain.domain@realFromAccordingToGoogle.org>\r\n"; 
$header .= "Organization: Our Company\r\n"; 
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
```

Does anyone knows how to write this code properly and make it work with Kohana framework.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What email class are you using (where did you get it)? Is there no documentation?

Comment: I am checking this folder: myproject\system\vendor\swift and I can see we use Swift Mailer Core Component v3.3.2 and also EasySwift: Swift Mailer Facade v1.0.3

Comment: Ok, so Swift Mailer has a [documentation on using headers](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/headers.html) and if you search your EasySwift class (I didn't find doc online), you'll find methods such as `addHeaders()` or `setHeader()`

Comment: Thanks! I found the documentation just here: http://swiftmailer.org/docs/headers.html

Comment: How would this avoid spam filters?